# Prove a sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove that $\lim \frac {(-1)^n} {n}=0$

this is in an introduction to analysis textbook in the section where $\epsilon   $ and $ \delta $ are introduced so im like 100% certain thats how they want it proved but im terrified of the dam things. i am wondering if this works as we have already proved that lim $\frac{1}{n} =0$

When n is odd $\frac {(-1)^n} {n}= \frac {-1} {n}$ when n is even $\frac {(-1)^n} {n} = \frac {1} {n}$  i want this somehow to state rigorously that

$\frac {-1} {n} \leq\frac {(-1)^n} {n} \leq \frac {1} {n}$ for all n

since $\lim \frac {(-1)} {n}=0$ and $\lim \frac {1} {n}=0$

thus $\lim \frac {(-1)^n} {n}=0$

is this rigorous enough?

Comment: Yes this is rigorous and you are applying sandwich theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn Landon Carter's comment into an answer, I would say almost. You probably want to say that you're applying the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to make it a full proof.